# Trouble computing gradient of $\mid f(z) \mid^2$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am implementing a published algorithm for optimal design of a digital filter. As part of the algorithm, I need to compute the gradient of  $\mid H(z)\mid^2$. Where 
$H(z)=\frac{(a_0+a_1z+z^2)}{(b_0+b_1z+z^2)}$. The derivative should be WRT coefficients $(a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1)$ and not WRT (z). The $(a_i, b_i)$ coefficients are real and the value of $z$ is on the unit circle.  I don't know how to proceed cause $\mid z \mid$ is not differential. Or is this differential WRT real coefficients $a_0, a_1, b_0, b_1)? If it is please explain. The paper I found the algorithm in suggests this computation isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the gradient is WRT the coefficient since if so, no need to use complex anaylsis by defining $z$ be a constant while it canbe found no matter $\bar z$ is differentiable.

if you want to find $\nabla\left(|H(z)|^2\right)$

Note that if $A(x,y)=P(x,y)+iQ(x,y)$ , $A(x,y)=B(z,\bar z)$, then $$gradiant(A)=\nabla A=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)(P+iQ)=\frac{\partial P}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial y}+i\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)=2\frac{\partial B}{\partial\bar x}$$

$$\nabla\left(|H(z)|^2\right)=\nabla(H\bar H)=H\nabla(\bar H)+\nabla(H)\bar H$$
$$H(z,\bar z)=\frac{(a_0+a_1z+z^2)}{(b_0+b_1z+z^2)}$$
$$\bar H(z,\bar z)=\frac{(a_0+a_1\bar z+\bar z^2)}{(b_0+b_1\bar z+\bar z^2)}$$
$$\nabla H=0$$$$\nabla\bar H=2\frac{\partial\bar H}{\partial \bar z}=2\frac{(a_1+2\bar z)(b_0+b_1\bar z+\bar z^2)-(b_1+2\bar z)(a_0+a_1\bar z+\bar z^2)}{(b_0+b_1\bar z+\bar z^2)^2}$$$$\nabla\left(|H(z)|^2\right)=H\nabla(\bar H)=2\frac{(a_0+a_1z+z^2)}{(b_0+b_1z+z^2)}\frac{(a_1+2\bar z)(b_0+b_1\bar z+\bar z^2)-(b_1+2\bar z)(a_0+a_1\bar z+\bar z^2)}{(b_0+b_1\bar z+\bar z^2)^2}$$

Comment: I see a problem there cause Conjugate(z) is not differentiable. However, I really do want derivatives WRT (a0, a1, b0, b1) as the purpose is to find optimal values of those variables. The gradient is very useful for that. The good news is that you pointed out that abs(H(z))^2 = H(z) conjugate(H(z)) = H(z) H(conjugate(z)). From there it's easy. .... All in ASCII since I am sending from my iPhone.